# Removing variations labels and redirect in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint

Customer wants to remove the variations redirect feature. We had only two variation labels, and I have already removed the target URL root/EN/ label that customer does not use anymore. Some content is copied to another location and then root/en can be deleted. Currently I still have the Source URL root/FI/ label left.

Now it seems to work more or less OK. So when user loads the root / it always redirect the user to source label. If I also remove the /FI/ label it does not redirect the user anymore and user receives an error.

How to properly configure this so that we don't have labels but user is always redirected to root/FI/ site?
OR if there is a way to set the root to be root/FI so that no redirects needed?